# What is $\sin(1+\sin(1+\sin(1+\sin(1+\cdots))))$(in radians)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

**I do not know what to tag this, so please make any edits for the tags if you can, thanks.**

In the infinite series (or whatever you would call that) above, what is the answer, and how does one get there?

Comment: Degrees or radians?

Comment: If it is radians, I think it is $\pi$.

Comment: You can look at this as being the limit of the recursively defined sequence $a_{n+1} = \sin(1+a_n)$, where $a_1 = \sin 1$.

Comment: @Jake:  the sine of anything real is in the range $[-1,1]$, so it can't be $\pi$

Comment: Wow, you are right @RossMillikan. I was thinking of the iteration $a_0(x)=x$ and $a_n(x)=x+\sin(a_{n-1}(x))$ which I once investigated and just plugged in $1$. (This, I think, converges to a step function increasing in steps of $\pi$ ). I feel like an idiot now. :)

Answer (score 4):

It is the limit

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$$

of the sequence

$$a_{n+1} = \sin(1+a_n)$$
with
$$a_0 = \sin 1$$

Which, if exists, is the solution of the equation

$$L = \sin(1+L)$$

$$L \approx 0.934563$$

For proving convergence, we need to show that $a_n < a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ is bounded above. The latter is trivial since $\sin x \leq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

It's Picard iteration time. Here is is in Radians. Run this.

```
import math
def f(x):
    return math.sin(1 + x)
x = 0
for k in range(40):
    x = f(x)
    print("%s\t\t %s" %(k, x))

$ python sine.py
0        0.8414709848078965
1        0.9635907245418334
2        0.9238430524420609
3        0.938323639041627
4        0.9332186565355136
5        0.9350407543894885
6        0.9343931955352627
7        0.9346236881728232
8        0.934541691349568
9        0.9345708670774895
10       0.9345604866259262
11       0.9345641799848324
12       0.9345628659013239
13       0.9345633334488618
14       0.9345631670968333
15       0.9345632262844155
16       0.9345632052256438
17       0.9345632127182946
18       0.9345632100524309
19       0.9345632110009376
20       0.9345632106634616
21       0.9345632107835347
22       0.9345632107408129
23       0.9345632107560132
24       0.934563210750605
25       0.9345632107525292
26       0.9345632107518446
27       0.9345632107520881
28       0.9345632107520015
29       0.9345632107520324
30       0.9345632107520213
31       0.9345632107520253
32       0.9345632107520239
33       0.9345632107520244
34       0.9345632107520242
35       0.9345632107520243
36       0.9345632107520243
37       0.9345632107520243
38       0.9345632107520243
39       0.9345632107520243
```

Comment: Brute force for the win, the simplest of strategies!

Comment: It's how you find a fixed point, this one for $x\mapsto \sin(1 + x)$.

Comment: Yes, I know.  Still, somewhat of a brute force calculation you performed there.

Comment: It's really the only tool in the drawer here.

Comment: :D  And use all the tools you have my friend.

Answer (score 1):

You can take by example, $a_0=1$ and $\forall n\ge 1: a_{n+1}=\sin(1+a_n)$.

First you need to prove that this sequence converges. May be because it is increasing and bounded?

Then you need to find the limit of this series, which can be done by taking the limit when $n\rightarrow\infty$ in the recurrence identity.

Roughly speaking, if you take $a=\sin(1+\sin(1+....$ then $\sin(1+a)=a$. Does this equations have any solution? If yes, how many?